# Moving entry between calendars

Tags: calendar

I have a number of Google calendars open on my phone.  Sometimes I add things to wrong one.
I can't see a way of moving items on the standard application.  Does any other Calendar app gave this feature?

Comment: Huh...how about that. That seems to be an oversight on their part. I suppose it goes without saying that it's academic to do in the web interface.

Comment: I've been looking at this and I don't think it's possible.

Comment: As of this moment, Google still has yet to implement this capability on Android, which is absurd, given that it's possible in Google Calendar's web-based interface and in dozens of third-party apps (for both Android and iPhone). This question was asked six years ago and still no movement from Google. Pathetic.

Comment: Hi all, I'm from 2018 and it's still not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Business Calendar Pro](https://market.android.com/details?id=mikado.bizcalpro) (and maybe even the free version) can move events from one calendar to another, even if they are on different accounts. I got Business Calendar Pro when I was still using the Samsung TouchWiz UI because I did not like their calendar application. Now that I am on a Vanilla Android, I still use Business Calendar Pro. The agenda widget is nice and the UI and functionality exceeds the stock calendar app.

[image]

Comment: Yes free version does this.  other nice features

Answer (score 1):

There is also an excellent (swiss made) app for bulk operations with events across all available calendars (including the local one): move, copy, delete. The events can be filtered by a lot of parameters:

Copy Calendar Events Pro

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.applisto.copyevents.pro

Comment: What is your connection, if any, to this app? Are you the developer, company owner, or other? Users should disclose their affiliation or the post may be deleted as suspected spam.

Comment: Hi @wbogacz, fair point! But no, I have no special connection to this app beside being a happy user since a few days :) I spent a LOT of time to figure out how to (partially) move events from one calendar to another and just wanted to help others which could be in the same situation.

Comment: Works great. Had events everywhere.... Now all in one place.